# Calculate the integral $\int_{x}^{2x}{\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^{4}+t^{2}+2}}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate the following integral
>   $$\int_x^{2x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+2}}$$

My approach: If complete the square, we have $$t^4+t^2+2=\left(t^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}+2=\left(t^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{7}{4}$$

So, let $\left(t^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{4}}\tan(\theta)$, then $2\,dt=\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{4}}\sec^2(\theta) \, d\theta$. Replacing in the integral, we have
$$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+2}} =\int \frac{\sec(\theta) \, d\theta}{2t}$$
How continues this??, I don't think this is the better way. Any help, plis.

Comment: @asdasdasd There is no elementary antiderivative for this integral. Where you perhaps asked to take the derivative of this integral instead (with respect to x)>

Comment: @asdasdasd: Is the integral written correctly, because it is [*ugly*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28t%5E4+%2B+t%5E2+%2B+2%29) or was it asking for a derivative?

Comment: There is a typo: The differential satisfies $2 t\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{7}{4}} \sec^2 \theta \,d\theta$.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Sorry for the question, but How you know this integral doesn't have elementary antiderivative?

Comment: @asdasdasd Well, you try for a couple minutes to find one, and then you realize it's impossible. So you go on the trusty [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com), and check.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Lol, ok. I thought there was some other method. Thanks!

Comment: @asdasdasd I'm sure there are different methods, that most likely depend on the form of the integrand (see the argument given by Luican below).

Comment: Is this a question you are asked to answer? Or were you asked for the derivative of the expression, which is straightforward?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I search determine the elementary antiderivative, but the expression is beyond my current course

Answer (score 1):

The integrand does not possess an elementary anti-derivative. See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information. More to the point, non-trivial integrals of algebraic functions containing elements of the form $\sqrt{P(x)},$ where **P** is a cubic or quartic polynomial, are expressible in terms of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), if at all.

As an aside, we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2+\color{red}1}}=K\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg),$ see [OEIS A$249282$](http://oeis.org/A249282).